# RPi AP works on laptop, not android

Tags: android, apache-httpd

I have a Rpi set up to act as an access point, I'm running a basic web server and going to run scripts.  I have my laptop connected to the Rpis Wifi, and can access the IP address and run my test script.

On my phone, I connect to the RPis Wifi, and go to the IP address, and it says "Connection timed out" almost immediately (within a second) and doesn't run the script.

What could be limiting the phones browser but allowing the laptops browser to work?  Its a direct connection to the RPis AP, so no firewalls or anything in the way.

Comment: Can you do some trouble shooting. Run both https://[ip] and http://[ip]. Do a wireshark scrape on the Pi and see if you can see anything. Check your iptables log: /var/log/iptables . Is the cert on the webpage (if 443) self signed?

Comment: The https fails on laptop as well.  The Pi can see that the phone is connected, it gives it an IP address.  EDIT:: Enter too early:  I think its an issue with not having a secure connecting (http vs https), is there a way I can get a certificate for the pi's AP?  Im trying to google it but I dont really know what to look for...

Comment: This was my instinct was that your browser is auto-blocking. Try installing chrome or firefox.

Comment: Was using chrome, installed firefox and tested that as well, no luck :/